# Error Fetching data node js from postgreSQL database show on web html

Tags: html, node.js, postgresql, dust.js

**An TypeError occurred while I was Fetching data from the postgreSQL database Where do I have errors and I need help!**

```
const { ENGINE_METHOD_ALL } = require('constants');
var express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    cons = require('consolidate'),
    dust = require('dustjs-helpers'),
    pg = require('pg'),
    app = express();

var connect = "postgres://postgres:admin@localhost/db1";

app.engine('dust', cons.dust);

app.set('view engine', 'dust');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

    
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    pg.connect(connect, function(err, client, done) {
        if(err){
            return console.error('error fetching client from pool Data', err);
        }
        client.query('SELECT * FROM tbl_employee', function(err, result){
            if(err){
                return console.error('error query', err);
            }
            res.render('index', {tbl_employee: result.rows});
            done();
        });
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('server Started on port 3000');
});
```

There was an error warning.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfzmW.png)

Comment: Do not link to images for error messages. Copy and paste the text into your question above.

Comment: Look at examples here [pg](https://node-postgres.com/features/connecting)